# Проверить появление элемента JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, как в `js` сделать проверку на появление элемента на странице?

У меня автоматически через сторонний код подгружается элемент `<div id onesignal-popover-dialog>`
Нужно проверить, когда появляется это окно, а после вывести хотя бы `Alert`.

Подскажите как это сделать. После `C#` в `js` по-другому как-то циклы и паузы состоят.

Comment: какой элемент добавляется, можно разметку в вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```js
// раз в секунду ищем элемент
let i = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.querySelector("#onesignal-popover-dialog")){
        // если нашли останавливаем таймер и вызываем алерт
        clearInterval(i);
        alert("element found")
    }
}, 1000);

// эмуляция асинхронного добавления, через 2 секунды добавим элемент
setTimeout(function(){
  document.write("<div id='onesignal-popover-dialog'>hello</div>")
},1000)
```

Comment: Спасибо)))))))))

Comment: @Микка пожалуйста, обращайтесь

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам поможет [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Можно отслеживать изменения DOM.

Answer (score -1):

В моём ответе я отлавливаю событие `click` на элементе `div` с классом `click-me`. Когда по эл-ту кликнули, срабатывает событие, в котором мы описали появление `div` с классом `alert`. А так же вызовется функция('show_info_about_alert'), которая сообщит нам, что отображен `div` с классом `alert`.

На нативном:

```js
const cm = document.querySelector(".click-me");
cm.addEventListener("click", function(){
  const al = document.querySelector(".alert");
  al.style.display = 'block';
  show_info_about_alert();
}, false);

show_info_about_alert = () => console.log('Появился alert!');
```

```css
.alert{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="click-me">
  Show alert!
</div>
<div class="alert">
  Super!
</div>
```

С использованием библиотеки `Jquery`:

```js
$('.click-me').on('click', function() {
  $('.alert').css('display', 'block');
  show_info_about_alert();
});

show_info_about_alert = () => console.log('Появился alert!');
```

```css
.alert{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click-me">
  Show alert!
</div>
<div class="alert">
  Super!
</div>
```

Так же можно прикладываю сылку на [документацию с примерами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).